# How to solve "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:443 " in R

Tags: r, api, twitter

I am using R to do some tweets extraction. 
I created the app and got the customer key with a tweeter developer account.
but I got the error : 
" Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:443 "
after using the code below

```
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxx"
my_oauth <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey, consumerSecret=consumerSecret, 
                             requestURL=requestURL, accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)
my_oauth$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

I am using this tutorial to do some ideology analytics : https://github.com/pablobarbera/twitter_ideology

Saw there is another post have the same question , but no one answered, hope some one can provide some suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Have you try http instead of https?

Comment: @Sangwonkim tried and it shows :Error: Forbidden

Comment: Did you turn off firewall? Sometimes it's caused by firewall blocking.

Comment: Is the library that makes the requests updated? They deprecated old protocols a few months back

Comment: @Sangwonkim Turned off the firewall, still show the same error. Would it be because of the function?

Comment: @osowskit when I check the ROAUTH to use, it shows this warning : library(ROAuth)
Warning message:
package ‘ROAuth’ was built under R version 3.5.3   but seems should be the lastest version. just download

Comment: That library doesn't look like it was updated since 2015. You should open an issue in the repo in the OP and ask if they are aware of any issues